# Unpermitted parameters in Rails 5 using has_many, through

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I keep getting unpermitted parameters for my appointment model.

Here are my models

```
    class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :client
      belongs_to :trainer
    end

    class Trainer < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :appointments
      has_many :clients, through: :appointments
    end

   class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :trainers, through: :appointments
  end
```

Here's my controller, I just listed my private method for sake of brevity.

```
 def appt_params
    params.require(:appointment).permit(:appointment_date, client_id: [], 
    trainer_id: [])
   end
```

The error says unpermitted parameters for trainer, client.
Am I missing something in my strong parameters method?

Here is my appointments/new view

```
<%= form_for @appointment do |f| %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :appointment_date %>
  <%= f.collection_select :trainer, Trainer.all, :id, :first_name %>
  <%= f.collection_select :client, Client.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I added collection to my appt_params method and still getting the same error. I'm still getting the hang of Rails and any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used associations, only client_id and trainer_id is enough and those should of integer form not array.

So change your strong parameters method code to :

```
def appt_params
 params.require(:appointment).permit(:appointment_date, :client_id, 
 :trainer_id)
end
```

And your applications/new view to:

```
<%= form_for @appointment do |f| %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :appointment_date %>
  <%= f.collection_select :trainer_id, Trainer.all, :id, :first_name %>
  <%= f.collection_select :client_id, Client.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @ryanb082 Nice to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Was running with the same issue as you and after hours of debugging I was able to solve it:

Was my first time trying associations in Rails with models similar to you, so most documentation online recommends to define the foreign key's as `client_ids:[]` assuming your ids were arrays, when definitely they are integers as my parameters where

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LEcwQ56xYJGpq2zIs6Cz0YbU7B7mBKRa6rhspVIxo9vEB5/UoFUvHYiN0UC0krTiIp+d0tzhit6DZT1Z8PmYYg==", "califica"=>{"text"=>"hi", "grade"=>"5", "user_id"=>"1", "party_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Calification"}
```

I think this is due to `f.collection_select` taking as expected one value. So after hours of using the permit of arrays such as `:user_id => []` , `user_id:[]` I was getting always error of Unpermitted parameters.

Tried the answer of @Bharath (which is correct) but it was still not working, that's was when I realized that my old models weren't made with references (`ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'user_id' for Calification.):`) so I had to make a [references migration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration) to add a foreign key and then it was all working perfectly.